# Tangent Line is horizontal when???

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x)=2x^3+3x^2-36x+5$, then the tangent line to the graph $y=f(x)$ is horizontal when??

I need help with this problem, I'm studying for finals so can anybody help me how to figure out this problem or where to start at least.

Please Help!

Comment: The derivative of $f$ must be zero.

Comment: Did you compute the derivative ? If yes, how does it look like ? It should be familiar to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent line to the graph of $f(x)$ is horizontal at any point $x$ such that $f'(x)=0.$

To use your example, $f'(x)= 6x^2+6x-36.$ Now find which values for $x$ satisfy $f'(x)=0.$

$f'(x)= 6x^2+6x-36=0$

$\implies 6(x^2+x-6)=0$

$\implies 6(x+3)(x-2)=0$

$\implies$ when $x=-3$ and $x=2$, $f'(x)=0 \implies$ the tangent line at $x=-3$ and $x=2$ is horizontal.

Comment: @kbball hey thanks. I was actually able to figure out the answer when I realize that $f$ had to be set to zero. Your answer made sure I got the correct answer (which I did). So again thanks!!

Comment: @JohnBeal: you're welcome!